# Homology of $\mathbb{R}^3$ removing $3$ coordinate axes.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to calculate the homology of $\mathbb{R}^3$ removing $3$ coordinate axes.
Let this space be $X$. I was able to show that $\pi_1(X) =  \mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$ (via reducing the problem to calculating $\pi_1$ of $\mathbb{S}^2 - \{3 \text{ points }\}$. But how about its higher homology groups?

Instinct told me that they are all zero but I'm having a hard time justifying it.

In particular, I tried to use Mayer-Vietoris sequences on the $3$ complement of the hyperplanes of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that their intersection gives the desired space but I haven't seen Mayer-Vietoris sequences applied on triple of subspaces.

Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: If you tell us how you computed the fundamental group we may be able to indicate if the argument extends to do what you want.

Comment: Is the fundamental group really Abelian?

Comment: $\pi_1(\mathbb{S^2})-\{2n$ points$\} \ne \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space deformation retracts onto sphere with 6 points removed. It's a non-compact 2-manifold, therefore $H_n(X) = 0$ for $n \geq 3$, and also $H_2(X) = 0$, because sphere with 6 points removed is not compact.